The color formatting in Visual Studio 2022 text editor stops displaying after source code line 10,000
Began occurring only a week ago.
I have been utilizing Visual Studio for modifying my entire my source code.
For months now, my .swift code file has exceeded 10,000 lines. Abruptly, everything starting from the 10,000th line is in black and white, while everything preceding that is in color.
I recently upgraded VS.

Why in the world would you have a single source file with 10K+ lines in it?

Looks like a fix for this similar  issue is now available in preview release. Try out the fix by installing the most recent preview from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/.

This issue is similar to Javascript Files Lose Color Coding after 10000 lines of code,

the Editor team changed this behavior in 17.11 to avoid excessive UI delays in certain files. JavaScript, TypeScript, and Razor all use textmate grammars for syntax classification, and VS triggers extra garbage collections when processing more than 10,000 lines for these files.

Looks like this limitation is by design at this moment.
You can try out these workarounds(Feature Flags extension/Set VsRegEdit) in above ticket to see it they help. As this similar question is reported and marked as Fixed - Pending Release, we can focus on this to see if there is any update.
Besides, you can consider breaking up large source code files into smaller, more manageable pieces. This can help improve performance and maintain color formatting if it is convenient for you.

Unfortunately, breaking up a source code file requires hours of solving build errors and introduces the risk of new bugs in working code.  "If it's working, don't fix it."
SPEED:  Modern optimizing compilers don't care about source file size -- I don't believe there is any effect.
VS has very convenient capabilities that make working with huge files a snap.

I understand your concerns. From looking at this similar ticket, looks like the issue was fixed but Pending Release. You can focus on it to see if there is any update.

The issue referenced by Dou Xu-MSFT has been updated, and a fix has been implemented in the latest release (17.12.0).
You can update the line limit by going to :

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Advanced, and update "TextMate
parser line limit (required restart)".

